# SSRS 2016 Vertical Alignment Middle not Working

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I am using **SSRS 2016** to make a report.

I use **MIDDLE** for the **Vertical Alignment** so the text is in the middle of the box.

[image]

It changes to look correct in **Design View** but when I view it in **Report Viewer**, it looks like it's set to **TOP**.

More bizarrely, when it exports to Excel or PDF, it works fine. There are no extra spaces or Return characters - just static text.

[image]

Is there any way to get this working as it did in SSRS 2012? It used to work fine.

I have tried it in both **Visual Studio** and **Report Builder** with the same crappy results. Unfortunately, this report will mostly be viewed on-screen.

Comment: Does the Report Manager result vary from one browser (IE, Chrome, Edge. etc.) to another?

Comment: Have you checked to see if some css isn't affecting the alignment?

Comment: It is possible that it is still trying to word wrap.  Test it with a smaller font size and see if it still does that.  If that is the case, you may need to increase the text box width just a bit.

Comment: @R.Richards - it is working correctly with Chrome. I hadn't tried it before because Chrome usually doesn't display SSRS reports at all.

Comment: @WesH - It doesn't seem to be a Word Wrap issue - even **OCR** with the same size textbox is pushed to the top in IE (but apparently not Chrome).

Answer (score 4):

To fix this, within Text Box Properties - General, remove the checkbox for Sizing options - Allow height to increase.  It works, but don't ask me why.

Comment: Thanks, worked, but only on the second change. The setting in Report Builder 2016 is called CanGrow (at least for me)

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, if your text has trailing spaces, it might be forcing it to the top of the field. Add a RTRIM to your column to remove the trailing spaces and see if that helps with alignment.